# C# Aggregate argument

Tags: c#, ms-access, aggregate, oledb

- In C#, I would like to run the below query on Access

  ```
  query = @"SELECT Jobs.Client, Jobs.Name, Jobs.Area, 
                   Jobs.DevHours, Sum([Activities.Duration]) AS SumOfDuration
            FROM Jobs INNER JOIN Activities ON Jobs.ID = Activities.JobId
            GROUP BY Jobs.Client, Jobs.Name, Jobs.Area, Jobs.DevHours;";`
  ```
- After making the query, I am using a dataadapter to read and fill the data into a datatable:

  ```
  OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand
  {
      CommandText = query,
      Connection = connection
  };
  OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
  DataTable table = new DataTable();
  da.Fill(table);
  ```
- however in run-time I face an error, which is saying

> Cannot have Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object fields in aggregate argument ([Activities.Duration])

I really appreciate if someone can help me.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24733678/cannot-join-on-memo-ole-or-hyperlink-object

Comment: What type is `Activities.Duration` of? It _sounds_ like a time span or tick count, but the error indicates it's of a type that is not `Sum`able.

Comment: Thank you @RenéVogt for the hint. The database was modified without me knowing it, and indeed the data wasn't `Sum` able.